# Why Is This Exception Thrown When it Shouldn't Be?

Tags: c#, exception, console-application

I have the following (very simple) console calculator that does basic circle calculations:

```
using System;

namespace Circle
{
    class Program
    {
        /* Compute the area of a cricle given its radius. */
        public static double Area(double radius)
        {
            return Math.Pow(radius, 2) * Math.PI;
        }

        /* Compute the circumference of a circle given is radius. */
        public static double Circumference(double radius)
        {
            return radius * 2 * Math.PI;
        }

        /* Compute the diameter of a circle given its radius. */
        public static double Diameter(double radius)
        {
            return radius * 2;
        }

        /* Report the result. */
        public static string Result(double radius, double area, double circumference, double diameter)
        {
            return "- A circle whose radius is " + radius + " has the following properties: "
                    + "\n- Area: " + area.ToString("0.##") + "\n- Circumference: " + circumference.ToString("0.##")
                    + "\n- Diameter: " + diameter.ToString("0.##");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double radius = 0;
            char choice;
            while (true)
            {
            Calculate:
                {
                    // 1. Get the radius from the user. 
                    Console.Write("- Enter the radius of the circle: ");
                    try
                    {  // verify the input is of numerical type 
                        radius = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                        if (radius <= 0)  // check for negative values 
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(" [Error] Radius must be a positive value!");
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            continue;  // restart from the next iteration without executing the rest of the statements 
                        } // end if 
                    }
                    catch (FormatException e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(" [Error] " + e.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine(); // skip a line
                        continue;  // restart from the next iteration without executing the rest of the statements 
                    } // end catch 
                }
                // 2. Calculate the area, circumference, and diameter of the circle. 
                double area = Area(radius);
                double circumference = Circumference(radius);
                double diameter = Diameter(radius);
                // 3. Display the results. 
                Console.WriteLine(Result(radius, area, circumference, diameter));
            // 4. Ask the user whether to quit.
            Ask:
                {
                    Console.Write("- Do you wish to make another calculation [Y or N]? ");
                    choice = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
                }
                if (choice.Equals('Y') || choice.Equals('y'))
                {
                    goto Calculate; // return to the beginning of the Calculate block. 
                }
                else if (choice.Equals('N') || choice.Equals('n'))
                {
                    break; // exit 
                }
                else {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid choice! Press Y to continue or N to exit.");
                    goto Ask; // return to the beginning of the Ask block. 
                }
            }  // end while 
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you for using me. Have a nice day!");
            Console.WriteLine();
        } // end Main 
    }
}
```

After a calculation, the program asks the user whether they wish to make another calculation. If the user enters Y, the program prompts them to enter the radius again. If the user enters N, the program terminates.

There are, however, two fundamental issues:

1. If the user chooses to make another calculation by pressing Y, the program prompts the user to enter a value, but also executes the catch block and throws the exception. This is shown in the example output:

> - Enter the radius of the circle: 3
> - A circle whose radius is 3 has the following properties:
> - Area: 28.27
> - Circumference: 18.85
> - Diameter: 6
> - Do you wish to make another calculation [Y or N]? Y
> - Enter the radius of the circle:  [Error] Input string was not in a correct format.
> - Enter the radius of the circle:

2. The second problem is when the user enters something other than Y or N, the program also shows unexpected behavior, like in the output:

> - Enter the radius of the circle: 4
> - A circle whose radius is 4 has the following properties:
> - Area: 50.27
> - Circumference: 25.13
> - Diameter: 8
> - Do you wish to make another calculation [Y or N]? j Invalid choice! Press Y to continue or N to exit.
> - Do you wish to make another calculation [Y or N]? Invalid choice! Press Y to continue or N to exit.
> - Do you wish to make another calculation [Y or N]? Invalid choice! Press Y to continue or N to exit.
> - Do you wish to make another calculation [Y or N]?

I can't seem to figure out why either of these is happening. I suspect it's my use of `goto` and `continue`, but I couldn't tell.

Comment: You really shouldn't use `goto`. It's bad.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I know it's not the best idea, but it seemed to make perfect sense for this situation. If you have other suggestions or alternatives, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Functions would be a more elegant solution than `goto` statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your `Convert.ToChar(Console.Read())`. That reads a character from the input, but the input doesn't get set from the console until enter is pressed. So the `Console.Read()` correctly gets the `'Y'`, but the input has an <kbd>ENTER</kbd> queued up so your `Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine())` gets an empty string that it tries to convert and hence the exception.

Change the `Convert.ToChar(Console.Read())` to `Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine())` and it works fine.

You should also get rid of the `goto`s and also get rid of the exception trapping - you should use `double.TryParse(...)` instead. No more exceptions.

---

I did a refactoring of your code for you to try - no `goto`s and not exception handling.

```
while (true)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("- Enter the radius of the circle: ");
        double radius;
        if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out radius) && radius > 0.0)
        {
            double area = Area(radius);
            double circumference = Circumference(radius);
            double diameter = Diameter(radius);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(Result(radius, area, circumference, diameter));
            break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(" [Error] Radius must be a positive value!");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    string choice = "";
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("- Do you wish to make another calculation [Y or N]? ");
        choice = Console.ReadLine();
        if (new [] { "Y", "N", }.Contains(choice.ToUpper()))
        {
            break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("- Invalid choice! Press Y to continue or N to exit.");
    }
    if (choice.ToUpper() == "N")
    {
        break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("- Thank you for using me. Have a nice day!");
Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: That totally fixed it. I admit, my understanding of the difference between ReadLine() and Read() is rudimentary. No surprise what I did there! Thank you!

Comment: Just a heads-up on the refactored version: I copied it into my IDE to test it out but it tells me that there is no 'Contains' method, so it's giving me an error because of that. I'm using C# 6.0 with VS 2015. (I get the general logic behind the modified program, though.)

Comment: You need a reference to `System.Linq`, I think, for `.Contains` to work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your use of `Read()` and `ReadLine()`, and how the input is sent to from the shell to the `Console` object.

In the Console object, the input stream (buffer) is only loaded after [Enter] is pressed.  At that point, `Read()` will return the next unread character in the string, but *only that one character*.  When `ReadLine()` is subsequently called, it goes to the buffer where the newline character is still waiting, so it immediately returns (in this case) an empty string.  Hilarity ensues.

Remediation is left as an exercise for the reader ;)

Comment: If by homework you mean a problem I devised for myself as a beginner C# user, then you'd be correct. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Fair enough!  I remember doing the same with a few languages myself.  Thusly edited.

Comment: No worries. Thank you again :)